# Is there a way to prevent a function/method from being called outside a specific hook?

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

I would like to make function only callable by a specific action, in this case the `register_activation_hook()` function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Wordpress function [current_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter/) that retrieves the name of the current filter or hook that called a function/method. You can match it to a whitelist and either end or continue the function based on the result.